# AuthGuard canActivate with http request for roles

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a strange situation. My AuthGuard is more complicated than usual.
It's depending on authentication token + on user role.

So whenever canActivate is fired I have to check if the user is authenticated and then check if he has a permission to go to the route it wants.

Permission checking is handled in backend so I'm only have to make request and get response, whether the user is permitted or no.

I don't know how to achieve this. Checking auth token is easy, but how to combine this with http request? I don't know. I tried many solutions, but always I get error or infinity waiting.

Here is my code for canActivate method. Note that `checkPermission` is `http.get(...)`

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    return this.store.select('auth').pipe(
      take(1),
      map((state: State) => {
        if (state.token) {
          return this.checkPermission(state, route).pipe(
            map(res => {
              if (res) {
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            })
          );
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }));
  }
```

Comment: I guess that `this.checkPermission(state, route)` is returning observable, in that case you should use switchMap instead of map inside main pipe

Comment: @GogaKoreli I tried this but there are errors, like e.lift is not a function

Comment: what is the source line which throws that exact error?

Comment: @GogaKoreli please have a look on Narek answer

Comment: By the way please note that your way of doing this thing is not ideologically correct. I mean the fact that you send the request to the backend on every canActivate is very heavy for client and backend as well. You should get the list of permissions and check the client side navigation permissions locally. Don't think that I am avoiding your problem, I am just suggesting better architecture.

Comment: yea, you have right probably :)

Answer (score 0):

use switchMap

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    return this.store.select('auth').pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((state: State) => {
        if (state.token) {
          return this.checkPermission(state, route);
        } else {
          return of(false);
        }
      }),
      map(res => !!res)
    );
  }
```

Comment: I get main.dd7f4d98ff8e78017d91.js:formatted:15730 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: e.lift is not a function

Comment: I don't know the stack trace is weird